# Aligning multline equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I have tried `align` and `alignat` as well, but I can't get the proper alignment for my group of equation. The problem is with the second line, which is a second part of the first equation. I want it to go further to the right, something like `multline` environment output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{align}
f_{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}}(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n};\boldsymbol{\theta})&=f_{X_{n}|X_{n-1},\ldots, X_{1}}&&(x_{n}|x_{n-1},\ldots, x_{1},\boldsymbol{\theta}) \nonumber \\  
&&f_{X_{1},\ldots, X_{n-1}} (x_{1},\ldots, x_{n-1};\boldsymbol{\theta}) \nonumber \\
&=f_{X_{1}}(x_{1};\boldsymbol{\theta}) \prod_{t=2}^{n} f_{X_{t}|X_{t-1},\ldots,X_{1}}(x_{t}|x_{t-1},\ldots,x_{1};\boldsymbol{\theta}).
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of these:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    f_{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}}(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n};\boldsymbol{\theta})&= \begin{multlined}[t]f_{X_{n}|X_{n-1},\ldots, X_{1}}(x_{n}|x_{n-1},\ldots, x_{1},\boldsymbol{\theta})\\
  \times f_{X_{1},\ldots, X_{n-1}} (x_{1},\ldots, x_{n-1};\boldsymbol{\theta})\end{multlined} \nonumber \\
    &=f_{X_{1}}(x_{1};\boldsymbol{\theta}) \prod_{t=2}^{n} f_{X_{t}|X_{t-1},\ldots,X_{1}}(x_{t}|x_{t-1},\ldots,x_{1};\boldsymbol{\theta}).
    \end{align}


    \begin{align}
    f_{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}}(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n};\boldsymbol{\theta})&= \begin{aligned}[t]f_{X_{n}|X_{n-1},\ldots, X_{1}}(x_{n}|x_{n-1},\ldots, x_{1},\boldsymbol{\theta})\\
  \times f_{X_{1},\ldots, X_{n-1}} (x_{1},\ldots, x_{n-1};\boldsymbol{\theta})\end{aligned} \nonumber \\
    &=f_{X_{1}}(x_{1};\boldsymbol{\theta}) \prod_{t=2}^{n} f_{X_{t}|X_{t-1},\ldots,X_{1}}(x_{t}|x_{t-1},\ldots,x_{1};\boldsymbol{\theta}).
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first one seems to mess up the spacing between equations. Do you know what could fix that? Or is there a way that would allow me to move the middle line of the second one to the right?

Comment: `multlined` uses a smaller vertical skip between its lines, I suppose to emphasize the second line is a continuation of the first. If you don't want this, replace `\\ ` at the end of the first line with `\\[0.4ex] `.